# Add space between JList items

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

How can I add a space between `JList` items? is there a way doing it?

On this Image white is the background and yellow is the customize `DefaultListCellRenderer` of `JList` and I want each of the `JList` Item to have a space like 5 pixels to each other.

http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/5772/spacemd.png

```
dlm = new DefaultListModel<String>();
jlist = new JList<String>(dlm);
jlist.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,16));
jlist.setCellRenderer(new Renderer());
jlist.setFixedCellWidth(100);
jlist.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10, 10, 10));
```

Comment: Typically this would be achieved by adjusting the renderer.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: andrew can you tell me where to start with it?  I know how to render but i dont know here to start. thanks

Comment: @asda Sdasd `(wrote I tried it but it is expanding the yellow background)` another of reasons for SSCCE

Comment: What i mean is inside the renderer what code that will make a space? Y_Y

Answer (score 3):

I don't see your renderer, but you can add the component to a panel. This one relies on the default five pixel gap from the default `FlowLayout`, but you could add a border to the panel, too.

```
list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer(){
    private static final int N = 2;

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(
            list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(c);
        return p;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `JList.setFixedCellHeight(someValue),` usually will do the same.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland Not really, renderer.getPreferedSize() is only used when fixedCellHeight != -1. See `BasicListUI.updateLayoutState()`.

Comment: Ok, must be something different with my L&F.